# Pointing to a location in Google Maps in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on an app using android studio where cell data is saved in a database with it's corresponding location in latitude and longitude coordinates and users can access this data when there is no service to find a way to a good to better service. The data will be drawn to a `google maps activity` and color coordinated to represent the color but I also want to add an arrow the points from `current location` to the best cell service within a radius that I will set up.

Is it possible to draw an arrow to accomplish the task of pointing to a data point that is drawn? any info that points me in the right direction or the answer will help, thank you.

**EDIT**
The arrow design I have in mind points to the better signal but does not connect to the other location. I will figure out a more complex pointing device later in development so I am just looking for information on the possibility of a short pointer arrow that represents a "GO THAT WAY" response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ground overlays , where you can set particular image at given latlong.

```
LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);

GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_nj_1922))
    .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);
map.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

for rotating the image  you can look

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4332278/7386743

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about creating line between the two points ? Could you clearify more what do you exactly need ?
If it creating a line then you can use **polyline**

```
GoogleMap map;
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
 .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
 .width(5)
 .color(Color.RED));
```

Comment: Useful, I'll look into it as well. I editted the question, hope it clarifies things

Comment: what i understood is, you want to create an arrow at particular point . Is it what you actually mean?

Comment: Yeah, aimed from the current location to the best signal